# Obtener el numero más pequeño mayor de -1

Tags: java, condiciones

Tengo un método que coge el indice a utilizar en un sistema de markdown propio.

Al metodo se le pasan indices y tiene que devolver el mas bajo mayor de -1 (not found) hasta ahora solo teniamos **`negrita`**, *`cursiva`* y `normal` y el metodo era relativamente sencillo (aunque me parece feo con ganas):

```
private int getValidIndexToUse(int indexOfBold, int indexOfItalics) {
    if (indexOfBold > -1 && indexOfItalics == -1)
        return indexOfBold;
    else if (indexOfItalics > -1 && indexOfBold == -1)
        return indexOfItalics;
    else 
        return indexOfBold > -1 && indexOfBold < indexOfItalics ? indexOfBold : indexOfItalics;
}
```

Ahora hay que añadir ***`cursiva+negrita`*** y subrayado y con este sistema el metodo se convierte en una locura.

Alguien tiene alguna idea mejor que anidar infinitos if's?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

El problema general de buscar el número más pequeño de un conjunto de números, con la condición de que sea mayor que otro número determinado, se podría simplificar un poco más con un parámetro de longitud variable:

```
private int getValidIndexToUse (int... indexes) {
  int toReturn = Integer.MAX_VALUE;

  for (int index : indexes)
      if (index > -1 && toReturn > index)
          toReturn = index;

  return toReturn;
}
```

O con Java 8, usando un stream de ints:

```
private int getValidIndexToUse (int... indexes) {
  return Arrays.stream(indexes).filter(i -> i > -1).min().orElse(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
}
```

Comment: Esta es una solución más general en caso que aparezcan nuevos casos.

Answer (score 2):

Pues posteando la pregunta he visto clarisimamente como hacerlo sin complicarme la vida, muy parecido a si quisieramos sacar el mismo resultado iterando a través de un array o lista:

```
private int getValidIndexToUse(int indexOfBold, int indexOfItalics, int indexOfUnderlined, int indexOfBoldItalic) 
{
    int toReturn = Integer.MAX_VALUE;

    if (indexOfBold > -1) toReturn = indexOfBold;
    if (indexOfItalics > -1 && toReturn > indexOfItalics) toReturn = indexOfItalics;
    if (indexOfUnderlined > -1 && toReturn > indexOfUnderlined) toReturn = indexOfUnderlined;
    if (indexOfBoldItalic > -1 && toReturn > indexOfBoldItalic) toReturn = indexOfBoldItalic;

    return toReturn;
}
```

**NOTA:** no se comprueba si todos son iguales a -1 porque la llamada del metodo esta dentro del un `while (containsAny(stringToCheck, TAGS))`, pero si no se realizara este check es un punto a comprobar.

---

Lo que me he dado cuenta es que habia un error de acercamiento al problema y excesiva complicación en el metodo antiguo, sumado a que en ciertos momentos te ofuscas, salen  metodos complicadisimos como el de la pregunta.

Espero que mi ceguera temporal le sirva a alguien en un futuro.